# How can I get my Square Connect location without using command line

Tags: php, square-connect

I want to start by saying I have searched extensively, including google, connect.squareup.com, and Stack Overflow and cannot find an answer to my question. I have posed this question to Square support, and (even though I mentioned I could not access command line and have already done the tutorial mentioned below, I was directed to said tutorial and told to use the command line that I can't use. Here's my problem...

I am trying to set up the square connect API on a webserver for a client. On the webserver, I do not have access to command line (or SSH without an additional cost to the client). The only ways I have found to get the location_id requires command line (as far as I can tell). Is there a way to not have to use command line? Or is there another way to put in the required command without command line access?

Here is what I have done so far:

I read somewhere (can't remember where now) that you can install composer locally, use command line on your machine to install the dependencies needed for square-connect, then move all the files to your server. I have done that to get the files on the server.

My file structure looks like this:
payment-portal/
    vendor/
        composer/
        square/
        autoload.php
        composer.json
    composer.json
    composer.lock
    composer.phar
    locations-test.php
    process-card.php

The locations-test.php contains:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$access_token = "ACCESS_TOKEN";
$location_api = new \SquareConnect\Api\LocationApi();
echo $location_api->listLocations($access_token);
```

Note: ACCESS_TOKEN has been replaced with my personal access token.

*Of coarse, if I access this file at mywebpage.com/payment-portal/locations-test.php, I get a blank page.*

Also, I am not getting any errors in the error log.

The way to get locations is lined out [here](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/processing-payment-php/).
Under "Retrieving your location IDs." I am OK up until this point, but I cannot use command line in my server to use the code:

```
php locations-test.php
```

What are my other options to get the location_id? What am I missing?

Thanks in advance for any help or direction!

Comment: If you're getting a blank page it could mean 1 of 2 things. Either the script doesn't produce any output (in which case you'll get an HTTP 200 OK response code from the server), or the script ended with errors, but you have [`display_errors`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) turned off (in which case the server *should* respond with an HTTP 500 Internal Error response code). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/33665510/1878262 for more details.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, @Sherif! I have turned on error reporting for the site, and this was the output:

Comment: Sorry, it is too long. I will post a link is a second.

Comment: Here is a link to the file: https://1drv.ms/t/s!AlxoxUJLRzvMhSZuQEhvX2qJX1pb

Comment: I agree with @Sherif that it might be a networking issue. Have you tried running the code on a local PHP environment?

Comment: @tristansokol - I do not have a local php environment set up on my system. I have a new computer with windows 10, and just haven't gotten to that yet. I will contact my webserver to see if any outgoing ports are being blocked as Sherif suggested. Thanks for the help, and I'll let you know the outcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the [php-sdk you're using for connecting to the square API](https://github.com/square/connect-php-sdk/blob/master/lib/Api/LocationApi.php#L99), the required format for `$access_token` should be `"Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"` no just your access token.

```
/**
 * @param string $authorization The value to provide in the Authorization header of
 * your request. This value should follow the format `Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE`.
```

Try using this instead and see if it works.

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$access_token = "Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN";
$location_api = new \SquareConnect\Api\LocationApi();
echo $location_api->listLocations($access_token);
```

Of course, don't forget to replace the `ACCESS_TOKEN` part with your own access token.

Comment: I changed it as you said, but I am still getting the same error message that was listed above.

Comment: I do realize that the file above has listLocationsWithHttpInfo(''), but the new one has ('Bearer sq......')

Comment: This could possibly be a network issue. Make sure the server you're running this PHP on has no blocked outgoing ports. Try asking the host provider for assistance with that.

Comment: It actually doesn't matter if 'Bearer' is included in the access token. Thanks for pointing out that inconsistency though!

Comment: @Sherif - I will check with the webserver to see if there are any blocked outgoing ports that could be preventing this, and I will get back to you all! Thanks so much for all the help!

Comment: @Sherif - You were absolutely correct. The problem was blocked outgoing ports on the server. They have gotten it fixed and everything works beautifully!!! :) I don't have the rep to upvote, but I have accepted it as the answer!